# ajax get data different frequency

Tags: javascript, ajax

My html page have two div, both use ajax get server data, but div-a get data by second, div-b

get data by minute, how can i implement this different frequency to get server data ?

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

use `setInterval`

```
 setInterval(function(){
     //ajax to get div-a
 }, 1000);

 setInterval(function(){
     //ajax to get div-b
 }, 1000*60);
```

Answer (score 1):

`pseudo-code:`

```
setInterval(function() 
{
    updateDivA();
}, 1000);

setInterval(function() 
{
    updateDivB();
}, 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: I don't know why this reformatting was better than my original two-liner, but I guess I have no objection.